# Hive metastore location

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Spark 1.3.1 supports Hive Sql.When I type `show tables`, it returns 
`A B C D` - 4 tables. I have a question that where Spark stores my 4 tables? is it `hive.metastore` location? I have deleted `hive.metastore` location but `show tables` still shows `A B C D`

Answer (score 5):

I saw this in [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) : "Users who do not have an existing Hive deployment can still create a HiveContext. When not configured by the hive-site.xml, the context automatically creates metastore_db and warehouse in the current directory."

So if you do not have any custom configuration it should be in your repo under warehouse.
You can change it like this :

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val hiveContext  = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sparkContext)
hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", $YOUR_LOCATION)
```

I also saw this in the doc : "When working with Hive one must construct a HiveContext, which inherits from SQLContext, and adds support for finding tables in in the MetaStore".

So I don't really understand how you could still see your table after deleted your metastore, maybe it was somewhere in memory.

---

Edit :

What I understood of this :

- metastore : headers of tables
- warehouse : tables